# Why does Arduino use external ground at the barrel jack side?

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, ground, eaglecad

Generally, I use ground "GND" from surface ground when designing PCBs with EAGLE, which is made with polygon -> ratsnest.

On Arduinos it looks like the GND pins also use a polygon surface GND, but I have noticed that the barrel jack side uses an external GND, and it connects the Arduino GND pins.

What is the main reason of this, are there any special reasons? Why not use surface ground everywhere?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not using dedicated PCB layers for GND/PWR planes but are mixing it with other traces, it is a very good idea to draw traces for each connection before applying the copper pour.

If you just add a GND pour to the top- and bottom plane on a 2-layer board like this, it is very difficult to control the ground resistance/impedance in specific places. You can easily break up the ground plane such that some components are indeed electrically connected to ground, but the current has to zig-zag back and forth through the entire board before getting where it's supposed to go, providing very high impedance.

So drawing traces for GND like this is a good idea, then you apply the copper pour once everything is connected. And add some via stitching as well.

For this specific case, the designer probably wanted to make sure there is a good enough connection from the barrel jack to those GND pins in the header.